# Rails Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)Please provide the root password for your MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new on rails, and i've got some problems with **rake db:create** using mysql on Linux.

This message is shown:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)Please provide the root password for your MySQL installation
```

I've searched on the internet and did a lot of things suggested, like:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('test') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Then tried to rake db:create again, but the problem persisted. Does anyone had this problem and can help me?

I also receive this message:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", "database"=>"voting_development"}
```

Solution:

On config/database.yml i've misspelled the password after the configuration of mysql password, after that it worked properly  , thanks to Wand Maker.

Comment: Have you updated database.yml correctly?

Comment: That was the problem, thanksss! I've mispelled the password on database.yml, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set root password by invoking MySQL console. It is located in

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\bin by default.

Get to the directory and type MySQL. then set the password as follows..

```
> SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('new-password');
```

2) You can configure wamp's phpmyadmin application for root user by editing

C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\config.inc.php 
It looks like this:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOURPASSWORD';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

The error "Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)" will be resolved when you set $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] to false

Note: phpmyadmin is a separate tool which comes with wamp. It just provide a interface to MySQL. if you change my sql root's password, then you should change the phpmyadmin configurations. Usually phpmyadmin is configured to root user.

Comment: I'm not using phpmyadmin, i'm using rails, but i've already used that command.